# Java: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Canvas.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am new to multi threading, I tried modifying this code to draw lines on canvas on seperate thread (Because it lags like hell and when music is playing - lines glitch not allowing me to add nice glows and blurs to lines).

I tried creating thread, app runs but it crashes and gives me:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.graphics.Canvas.getWidth()' on a null object reference

It's pointing to this line:

```
mCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Here is the class itself, I've cut out most parts that are not related to problem. onDraw is main problem for me.

```
/**
 * Copyright 2011, Felix Palmer
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://creativecommons.org/licenses/MIT/
 */
package com.pheelicks.visualizer;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.audiofx.Visualizer;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import com.pheelicks.visualizer.renderer.Renderer;

/**
 * A class that draws visualizations of data received from a
 * {@link Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener#onWaveFormDataCapture } and
 * {@link Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener#onFftDataCapture }
 */
public class VisualizerView extends View {
  private static final String TAG = "VisualizerView";

  private byte[] mBytes;
  private byte[] mFFTBytes;
  private Rect mRect = new Rect();
  private Visualizer mVisualizer;

  private Set<Renderer> mRenderers;

  private Paint mFlashPaint = new Paint();
  private Paint mFadePaint = new Paint();

  public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
  }

  public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public VisualizerView(Context context)
  {
    this(context, null, 0);
  }

  private void init() {
    mBytes = null;
    mFFTBytes = null;

    mFlashPaint.setColor(Color.argb(50, 255, 255, 255));
    mFadePaint.setColor(Color.argb(200, 255, 255, 255)); // Adjust alpha to change how quickly the image fades
    mFadePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));

    mRenderers = new HashSet<Renderer>();
  }


  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        private Canvas canvas;
        public void setData(Canvas canva){
            this.canvas = canva;
        }
        public void run() {
            // Create canvas once we're ready to draw
            mRect.set(0, 0,getWidth(), getHeight());

            if (mCanvasBitmap == null)
            {
                mCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            }

            if (mCanvas == null)

            {
                mCanvas = new Canvas(mCanvasBitmap);
            }

            if (mBytes != null)

            {
                // Render all audio renderers
                AudioData audioData = new AudioData(mBytes);
                for (Renderer r : mRenderers) {
                    r.render(mCanvas, audioData, mRect);

                }
            }

            if (mFFTBytes != null)

            {
                // Render all FFT renderers
                FFTData fftData = new FFTData(mFFTBytes);
                for (Renderer r : mRenderers) {
                    r.render(mCanvas, fftData, mRect);
                }
            }

            // Fade out old contents
            mCanvas.drawPaint(mFadePaint);

            if (mFlash)

            {
                mFlash = false;
                mCanvas.drawPaint(mFlashPaint);
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(mCanvasBitmap, new

                            Matrix(),

                    null);
        }
    }).start();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kon I thought I am assigning it via public void setData(Canvas canva)?
Originally canvas comes from onDraw.

Comment: So who is calling setData since your Runnable is anonymous? Also you'll be doing draw calls on your own thread - which isn't the UI thread...